# Images, Caching and Sprites in Android

Tags: android, android-image, sprite

I've got a really simple (so far) Android app, which basically shows your friends on a Google Map. Think Latitude.

The friends are represented as avatar pins, the images of which are downloaded from the internet.

When a "friend" is added, i fetch the avatar in a background thread. I then don't need to download the avatar again (i'll probably check for updates during app start, but not too fussed about that right now). The actual images will most likely come from a social network (Facebook, Google, Twitter, Gravatar, etc)

Now, the map view will basically **always** be displayed, so the images are essentially always present. I will however be performing image manupilation, stacking, etc for these avatars.

Given the above information, here are my questions:

1. Where should i cache these images? Looking at the [docs](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/cache-bitmap.html), i feel like a **Disk Cache** would be the best option?
2. Should i think about creating an image sprite? Remember, these images don't live in the APK/resources, they are dynamically fetched. Perhaps i could create a per-friend sprite with all the different image sizes i will require?
3. I also have access to the server which returns these images (right now they just return a URL) - so should i enable this server to instead do image processing/resizing etc based on my requirements, or simply download the original image and then perform the processing on my client application?

Answer (score 0):

You can use lazy loading to dynamically download the users images from the URl and store it in cache. I believe this link would help you out in this :

https://github.com/thest1/LazyList